# Error: References interface "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface" but no such service exists - while adding a flash

Tags: symfony

I am trying to add a flash message in my controller but I've been unsuccessful so far.

I get an error that says:

```
Cannot resolve argument $contactService of "App\Controller\ContactController::index()": Cannot autowire service "App\Service\ContactService": argument "$flash" of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Flash\FlashBagInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a class that implements this interface?
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W77ke.png)

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD2XN.png)

Comment: What's your question about this error message?

Comment: i dont know how to solve it, in my contact form when i click on send button it give me this error @NicoHaase

Comment: Please add the code in your second image as proper text (code formated) in the question, and format your error text as code.

Comment: Is this symfony 6? In symfony 6 the `session.flash_bag` was removed so it can't be used as a "standalone" service anymore. So the answer is correct, in your `ContactService` you can use the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack` service to get to the session object which gives you the flash bag.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referencing an interface that doesn't have a class implementing it, then Symfony tries to find it and as there is no class available, it throws an error.

If you are trying to show a flash message, and your method extends from **AbstractController** then the correct way is as:

```
$this->addFlash($type, $message)
```

Instead of your injection and posterior method calling `$this->flash->add()`.

**AddFlash()** is an **AbstractController** method that does this:

```
$this->container->get('request_stack')->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add($type, $message);
```

So if your method does not extend from it, you can always try to replicate this line in your own controller.

**Why does it say there is no class implementing the interface but `getFlashBag()` works?**

`getFlashBag()` is a method referencing a Service, this method is autowired to a class type/interface name, via type-hints. You can create your own services too.

The service that has access to the flashBag is `SessionInterface` (FlashBag extends from SessionBagInterface)

You can learn more [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#fetching-and-using-services):

> You can "ask" for a service from the container by type-hinting an
> argument with the service's class or interface name
>
> [...]
>
> When you use these type-hints in your controller methods or inside
> your own services, Symfony will automatically pass you the service
> object matching that type.